# DocuSign: Positioning of modified text with tags

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using Docusign API and just managed to upload a document. From the documentation I have been able to add different tabs ("SignTabs", "TextTabs" etc.) but I was wondering if it's possible to actually modify the text within the document.

For example if my document looks like this:

```
Hi {firstName},
Thanks for ordering {productName}.

Best regards,
{senderName},
{departmentName}
```

So basically is it possible to change the tag `{firstName}` using the DocuSign API when uploading a document, using `POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`, or would I need to handle these changes before uploading the document?

The issue I have encountered with using tabs, such as a `textTab`, is that the position of the whole document might change if the text becomes longer or shorter and therefore some tabs, with X- and Y-positioning, are off in the final document to the signer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use AutoPlace to dynamically place signing fields, you need to put {firstName}, {productName} etc as white text on white background and then using api you can replace these tokenize string with the DocuSign tabs and then populate actual text on these DocuSign tabs at the time of creating an envelope. You can find example of the same in the below link:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace

Answer (score 1):

If your fields have white space to their right (assuming a Left to Right language), then DocuSign's AutoPlace works well.

If the field is in the middle of a line, then your source document will need to leave room to the right, same as is done in old-style printed forms.

If you want the text to not have any extra space on the right, then you'll need to re-compose the document for each envelope that you sent. There are many PDF creation software packages and services available for doing this. Or you can create your documents in another file format and have either DocuSign or a 3rd party convert them for you.

[Document formats supported by DocuSign.](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/What-file-formats-are-supported-in-the-New-DocuSign-Experience) All of these source document types will be converted to PDF before they are shown to the signers.